# How can I create a hierarchical json response in FLASK

Tags: json, sqlite, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, hierarchical-data

I have a single table in database like [database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1E3I8.png). I want to search a child from database and return a hierarchical JSON to a front end in order to create a tree. How can I do that in FLASK.
My expected JSON for mat should be like [expected JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYkvV.png)

Comment: Could you please add your expected JSON format with the table data?

Comment: @avijitbhattacharjee, I have added the JSON format in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have tagged your question with [flask](/questions/tagged/flask), this post assumes you are using Python as well. To format your database values in JSON string, you can query the db and then use recursion:

```
import sqlite3, collections
d = list(sqlite3.connect('file.db').cursor().execute("select * from values"))
def get_tree(vals):
  _d = collections.defaultdict(list)
  for a, *b in vals:
    _d[a].append(b)
  return [{'name':a, **({} if not (c:=list(filter(None, b))) else {'children':get_tree(b)})} for a, b in _d.items()]
```

---

```
import json
print(json.dumps(get_tree(d), indent=4))
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "name": "AA",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "BB",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "EE",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "JJ",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "name": "EEV"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "FFW"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "KK",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "name": "HHX"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "CC",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "FF",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "LL",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "name": "QQY"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "MM",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "name": "RRV"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "GG",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "NN",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "name": "SSW"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "DD",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "HH",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "OO",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "name": "TTZ"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "II",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "PP",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "name": "UUW"
                                }
                             ]
                         }
                      ]
                  }
              ]
          }
      ]
   }
]
```